# onCreateOptionsMenu for imageview

Tags: android, gridview

i am  doing a android application for tablet in that

i have a gridView  in a view pager 
what i want to do is,
 i want to add menu to imageview in the gridView like google books

Please see this image for reference

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cf4Or.jpg

i tried placing this in the  gridView imageadaptor , no luck

```
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     // my code
     }
```

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `PopupMenu`:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html

You need to setup a `PopupMenu` giving a view as an anchor + specify the menu recourse that will be used here. Of course this should be done inside a `OnClickListener` for your view.

```
anchorView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context, anchorView);
        popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() { 
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.item_one:
                    // item one clicked
                    return true;
                case R.id.item_two:
                    // item two clicked
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        );
        popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu);
        popupMenu.show();
    }
});
```

Define a standard `menu` resource - here is your `popup_menu.xml`:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_one"
        android:title="Item one"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_two"
        android:title="Item two"/>

</menu>
```

Here is a nice tutorial that you can look at:
http://javatechig.com/android/popup-menu-in-android-example

Answer (score 1):

```
yourImageViewObject.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(activity, v);

                /** Adding menu items to the popumenu */
                popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, popup.getMenu());
                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.spam:

                            Toast.makeText(activity, "Spam clicked",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;

                        case R.id.blockuser:
                            Toast.makeText(activity, " Block user clicked",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;

                        case R.id.remove:
                            Toast.makeText(activity, "Remove clicked",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                        }

                        return false;
                    }
                });
                popup.show();
            }
        });
```

menu file main.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/spam"
        android:title="Spam"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/blockuser"
        android:title="Block User"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/remove"
        android:title="Remove"/>

</menu>
```

put above main.xml in menu folder inside res folder

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a [`PopupMenu`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html). Create a view that can act as the anchor for the menu and add the PopupMenu as follows:

```
PopupMenu myPopup = new PopupMenu(context, myAnchor);
myAnchor.setOnTouchListener(myPopup.getDragToOpenListener());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below steps... I hope this may help you

Step 1 : Create a menu items in menu resource folder
         Somewhat like this :

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
     <item android:id="@+id/menuitemone"
           android:title="Cut"/>
     <item android:id="@+id/menuitemtwo"
               android:title="Copy" />
     <item android:id="@+id/menuitemthree"
               android:title="Paste"/>
    </menu>
```

Step 2: Define an Image view for your individual griditem layout(according to your choice of placement)

Step 3: Define ImageView click listner in your BaseAdaptor class

Step 4: In onclick listner paste this code to show drop down menu

```
     PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, arg1);  
     popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menuname, popup.getMenu());  
     popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {  
     public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {  
             Log.i("TEST",item.getTitle());
             return true;  
         }  
       }); 
      popup.show();
```

You may need to see if you want a custom design for the same.
Google is your friend.